# Styling Grid in VaadinFlow

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin-flow

I've tried to change the background colour of my Vaadin Flow Grid's header via shared-styles.html (webapp/frontend/styles):

```
<custom-style>   
    <style>

        <dom-module id="my-grid" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
            <template>
                <style>
                    [part~="header-cell"] {
                        background-color: blue;
                    }
                </style>
            </template>
        </dom-module>

    </style>
</custom-style>
```

Corresponding to https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki/3.-Stylable-Shadow-Parts and https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/html-api/elements/Vaadin.GridElement this should work - but it doesn't ...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<dom-module>` should not be inside the `<style>` or `<custom-style>` tag, but beside it. In addition, it seems the background color will be overridden by the default, so you can try adding `!important` afterwards for testing. For me setting `th[part~="header-cell"]` seems specific enough to not get overridden.

```
<custom-style>
    <style>
    </style>
</custom-style>

<dom-module id="my-grid" theme-for="vaadin-grid">
    <template>
        <style>
            th[part~="header-cell"] {
                background-color: darkorange;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: To write the `<dom-module>` not inside but outside of `<custom-style>` was already sufficient - now it works - thank you!